# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Slow performance

Tags: performance

I am using ubuntu 14.04 64bit version in my following configuration system.
CPU - Intel i3 3.30 
Motherboard - Intel DH61BF
Ram - 4GB DDR3
Hard disk - 250GB sata

When i was using Ubuntu 13.04 32bit OS,it was working fine and performance was well.

But after installing Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, its too much slow.
I generally use Zend studio10,firefox and Google Chrome at same time and its working too much slow

Please, help me and do needfull.

Regards,
Kehul Patel

Comment: whats the architecture of PC, 64bit or 32bit. I think it might be the mismatch. Try 32bit ubuntu 14.04.